# Can a discrete random variable be manipulated just like a algebraic variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Can the discrete random variable **X** in  **P**(-2**X**>10**Y**) be manipulated into **P**(**X**<-5**Y**)

And furthermore can this be done to any other operations on **X**

Comment: Sure... save for undefined conditions (dividing by zero, etc.) you can perform valid mathematical operations on the conditions within your probability statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can do this. This is clear when you go back to the definition. If $X$ and $Y$ are defined on some probability space $\Omega$, that is,
$$X,Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R,$$ then
$$\mathbb P\{-2X>10Y\}:=\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega\mid-2X(\omega)>10Y(\omega)\}.$$

Clearly, conditions in a set can be transformed into equivalent conditions, so that we obtain:
$$\mathbb P\{-2X>10Y\}=\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)<-5Y(\omega)\}.$$

As before,
$$\mathbb P\{X<-5Y\}:=\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)<-5Y(\omega)\},$$
so that finally
$$\mathbb P\{-2X>10Y\}=\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)<-5Y(\omega)\}.$$

This can of course also be done with other kinds of operations.